# Mounting HFS+ drive on Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Tags: server, 16.04, mount, hfs+

I have Ubuntu 16.04 Server, and I'm trying to mount an HFS+-formatted drive on it. Surprisingly, there is absolutely no kernel support for the `hfsplus` VFS. I can install the userland tools (APT packages `hfsprogs` and `hfsutils`) and `fsck` or `mkfs` to your heart's content, but I can't mount the drive. If I type

```
cat /proc/filesystems | grep hfs
```

All I get is `squashfs`. If I type

```
modprobe hfsplus
```

I get the error

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module hfsplus not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic
```

How do I get HFS+ working?

Answer (score 0):

That filesystem driver doesn't seem to be installed in certain Ubuntu Server base images, particularly the kind you might get from SoftLayer or another VPS/cloud provider. To install HFS+ plus a bunch of other goodies, install the `linux-image-extra` package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Much of the modules in this package will be unnecessary for VMs (e.g., USB device drivers). It's really a shame that they're packaged together with filesystem drivers, but oh well!